# How to run Xcode 6 on macOS High Sierra(10.13)?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra

I downloaded Xcode from Apple Developer website. When I'm trying to open the app, it shows this error.

> You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode” with this version of macOS.

Can we bypass this check?

Comment: If you really need Xcode 6 for some reason, try to install Yosemite on virtual machine. Then install Xcode 6 on this virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about High Sierra (10.13), but here are steps to get Xcode 6 running on Sierra (10.12): https://indiestack.com/2016/08/xcode-6-on-sierra/

Haven't tried them myself though.

Comment: This works on High Sierra also. You need to launch it via the command line './Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode' and you will get some warnings, but it does run. Tried on 10.13.1 only.